# How to delete Firebase User, registered from Facebook provider?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have following code, for re-authenticating user:

```
checkAccountPassword(password) {
        if (this.isFirebaseUserLoggedWithFacebook()) {
            return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookToken - WHERE_CAN_I_FIND_THIS_TOKEN?????));
        }
        return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(firebase.auth().currentUser.email, password));
    }
```

Then I can delete user (because deleting require recent auth).

The problem is - that I cannot obtain token, that I need for reauth FB user.

I have code where I can obtain token, but it's just in case, when user have Facebook app installed, but if user using popup for login to Facebook, I don`t understand where can I get facebookToken

```
 doFacebookLogin() {
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            return from(this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile'])).pipe(
                switchMap(response => {
                    this.currentFacebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                    return from(firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(this.currentFacebookCredential));
                }),
                switchMap(() => {
                    return this.afAuth.idToken;
                }),
                first(),
            );
        } else {
            const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
            provider.addScope('email');
            provider.addScope('public_profile');
            return from(this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)).pipe(

                switchMap(() => this.afAuth.idToken),
                first(),
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I need to call doLogin() again, and save object to currentFacebookCredential, for popup-login-case this way:

```
return from(this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)).pipe(
                tap(userCred => {
                   this.currentFacebookCredential =  userCred.credential;
                }),
                switchMap(() => this.afAuth.idToken),
                first(),
            );
```